# Touch events not generated near bottom of screen? Samsung Galaxy S specific?

Tags: android, interface, mobile, hardware

I've found a strange problem with a Samsung Galaxy S phone that I cannot replicate on several other Android phones. I have several 40x40dip ImageButtons placed at the very bottom of the screen in a row. I can accurately press all these buttons on phones like the Droid and the Desire.

On the Samsung Galaxy S, it appears that the bottom few millimetres of the screen does not generate any touch events at all. To the user, it looks as if the buttons seem to only randomly respond to touch, but they work fine if you aim for their top edge. I can replicate this problem on the home screen as well where the (much larger) home screen buttons do not respond if you tap them at the very bottom. Has anyone else noticed this issue and had to workaround this? Is it common? I'm wondering if it a defect specific to the single handset I tried.

The only solution I can see is to make the buttons bigger but I don't want them taking up too much screen space as I'm making a CAD program and want the user to see more of the work area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it common?

Touch events near the edge of capacitive touchscreens tend to be less reliable. It varies by model, though.

> I'm wondering if it a defect specific to the single handset I tried.

It could be that your specific device, due to a defect, exhibits worse symptoms than average.